# how to install Apache Kafka in production Server?

Tags: apache-kafka

my C# producer and consumer projects are done.
they are ready for deploy and publish on my server.
but I confused on deploy Kafka on my windows server.
I have not docker or Kubernetes on my server .
how should I install Kafka on my server.
is that same as development mode install by command prompts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Docker or k8s. If you want to run it locally, then `kafka-server-start.bat` is what you'd use.

You really shouldnt run Kafka on Windows in Production, however, as mentioned by the errors included on [this page about using WSL2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/) regarding log (Kafka topic data) permissions; specifically, when the logs rotate/compact, you'll get some OS user file permissions exception

Comment: hi and thanks . according to link descriptions, i think  just choose is wsl2 . is that?

Comment: I cannot claim that WSL2 is worth using as a "production" server, either. If you cannot run Kafka in the cloud for some reason, then an actual Linux VM, would be your next best option rather than a Hypervisor